# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'pan'

Tags: jquery

For some reason, I'm getting this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'pan'
```

For this line of code:

```
$('#bg_1').pan({fps: 3, speed: 2, dir: 'right'});
```

I have connected the spritely plugin prior to this line of code as you can see here:
http://www.marioplanet.com/index.asp

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're including jQuery twice in the page, once here (line 12, in the `<head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and again here (line 91, in the `<body>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That second occurrence is wiping out the plugin, just remove line 91 `<script>` to resolve it.

Comment: Haha, thank you for that, I'm a little new at `#include`!  Thanks!